# What exactly does eig(A) and diag(A) return where A is a matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, vector

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code to Python with the numpy package, but not sure exactly what `eig(A)` and  `diag(A)` returns, where `A` is a matrix per my question title.

I have the following code in matlab for example:

```matlab
[U,autoval] = eig(S);
[d,i] = sort(-diag(autoval));

% where S is a 2 x 2 matrix, [1.1762 1.2076; 1.2076 1.5364]
```

In numpy, I am able to replicate the first line by doing:

```py
autoval, U = np.linalg.eig(S)
```

I have to filp the order. Correct me if I am wrong here, in MATLAB, what the first line `eig(S)`  returns is the eigen vector and the second is eigen value, where it is the opposite for python?

However in the second line, in MATLAB, the values returned are the following:

```
d = [-2.5772 -0.1353];
i = [2 1];
```

In python, after I run `d, i = np.msort(- np.diag(autoval))`:

```py
d = array([-0.1353, -2.5772]) # why is the order here different
i = array([0.0, 0.0]) # why is this different
```

Thanks in advance, cheers !!!

Answer (score 3):

Eigenvalues of a matrix have no intrinsic order. Both of your example codes in either [MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) or [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) return the eigenvalues in indeterminate unsorted order. Only the relation of the eigenvalue indices to the corresponding columns in the eigenvector matrix is determined.

[`np.msort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.msort.html) returns only the sorted array, not an additional array containing the sorted indices as the [MATLAB code](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) does. You happen to not notice this, because [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) returns a diagonal matrix, which after sorting can be split into two rows `d` and `i`.

If you want to have the indices, use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Also note that the eigenvalues are returned as 1-D array in the Numpy case, but 2-D matrix in the [MATLAB case](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html). Therefore the call to [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) is not needed in the Numpy case.

Comment: Thank you !!! Yes, you are right. I did not not notice ```sort``` in matlab also returns sorted indices. But somehow ```eig``` function in MATLAB and ```np.linalg.eig``` return different values too? Please reference to my above code, in Python, ```U = array([ [-0.7574, -0.6528], [0.6529, -0.7575] ] ])``` whereas in MATLAB, ```U = [-0.7575, 0.6529; 0.6529, 0.7575]```. Could you explain this please?

Comment: @Alex_Zhong These results are matching. There is just a slight difference in rounding and the second eigenvector (second column) differs by a minus sign. A scalar multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector to the same eigenvalue and multiplication by `-1` also doesn't affect the normalization. Therefore both results are equally valid and again there are no guarantees to get one or the other.

Comment: @unevent_mark, cheers man. Another difference of MATLAB and Python which confuses me is that, say I have an array ```Vt = [ [-0.087,  0.125,  0.236, -0.238], [-0.383, -0.503, -0.983, -1.1  ] ]```. In python, ```Vt[1, :]``` returns a 4 * 1 array ```[-0.383, -0.503, -0.983, -1.1  ]``` whereas ```Vt(1, :)``` in MATLAB returns a 1 * 4 array ```[ -0.0867    0.1253    0.2358   -0.2377 ]```. How can I deal with the dimension difference?